# Comma before "then"

Tags: commas

I just wrote the sentence below in an email and then doubted why I was putting a comma before each of the occurrences of "then".

To my inner ear, it seems natural to signal a pause in my *if/then* statements but I realized that I have no idea how this reads to a reader (or in this case a client).

Is this wrong, bad form, both? (I know the "a)" stuff is junk).

> If there are no problems, then there is a) a tested workaround and b)
>   confirmation that the issue is in pre-processing the text. If there is
>   still a problem, then I’ll have to dig further.

Comment: A comma before "then" is appropriate and necessary, i.e., after the "if" clause. However, "then" isn't a must.

Comment: You may get arguments both ways as to whether, as a matter of style, that comma should or shouldn't be there.  However, it is not "wrong" in that it separates "if" and "then" clauses.

Comment: @Sankarane - it *does* sound ok (and less ponderous) without the "then". I have a problem with "ponderousness" in my day-to-day writing.

Comment: Interesting! You have a problem with "ponderousness"? You mean, you ponder...a lot? Or, you make yourself sound too complex?

Comment: @Sankarane - perhaps the word I was looking for was. . . turgid.

Comment: @Sankarane - Ponderousness does _not_ mean to ponder. Two separate words/meanings. (@Tomato -turgid sounds a bit racy to me -maybe I've read too many naughty novels?)

Comment: @W9WBH - you may be thinking of "taut" as that seems to be the turgid cliché in many racy novels (not that I would really know. . .).

Comment: @W9WBH: Yeah, I guess I knew what 'ponderous' meant and that's why I asked if TOMATO was inclined to choose complex sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Obey your manual of style, either the one you've chosen or the one thrust upon you.  I use *The Chicago Manual of Style*, which recommends that you separate an introductory dependent clause (here, your *if*) from the main clause.